# Unit testing an Angular2 service that requires Electron

Tags: unit-testing, angular, electron

I'm working on an Electron app, using Angular2 (rc4) and Webpack. Unit test are ran with Karma.

I have a service that communicates with the electron process, which includes it in this way:

```
import { remote } from 'electron';

@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {
    main = remote.require('./main.js');
    settings: any;
    constructor() {
        this.settings = this.main.getSettings();
    }
}
```

When I want to write unit tests for this file, the karma runner throws this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "electron"
  at webpack:///src/app/services/settings.service.ts:9:0 <- spec-bundle.js:88524
```

If I add target:'electron-renderer' to the webpack.test.js config file, the error changes to:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
at webpack:/external%20%22electron%22:1:0 <- spec-bundle.js:83860
```

This is my webpack.test.js file:

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'

      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'null'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'null'
      }
    ],

    postLoaders: [

      {
        test: /\.(js|ts)$/, loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
        include: helpers.root('src'),
        exclude: [
          /\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$/,
          /node_modules/
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  target:'electron-renderer'
}
```

Question is: How do I run unit tests on an Angular2 component that communicates with the Electron process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use karma-electron.

The karma.conf.js should be changed to use electron as browser:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.test');

module.exports = function (config) {
    var _config = {
        basePath: '',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: [{ pattern: './spec-bundle.js', watched: false }],

        preprocessors: { './spec-bundle.js': ['electron', 'coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'] },

        webpack: webpackConfig,

        coverageReporter: {
            dir: '../coverage/',
            reporters: [
                {
                    type: 'text-summary',
                    type: 'json',
                    type: 'html',
                }
            ]
        },

        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },

        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        },

        reporters: ['spec', 'coverage'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['Electron'],
        singleRun: true,

        client: {
            useIframe: false
        }
    };

    config.set(_config);
};
```

However, this will still throw an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at <appath>/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:32
```

This is already solved in jasmine-core, but not yet in jasmine-npm (see: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1144

Workaround until a new npm version of jasmine-core is released is to use the direct github link instead of the npm package version in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ....
  "jasmine-core": "https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine.git",
  ....
}
```